# Is it possible for a long carbon chain to have both acidic and basic groups?

Tags: acid-base, hydrocarbons

I was reading about a [zwitter ion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwitterion) and I had a thought that is the same possible for an acidic and basic groups. Like a very long carbon chain with a basic group and an acidic group on either sides, I am guessing it’d be called amphoteric but amphoteric compounds themselves do not contain acidic and basic group, so is it possible to synthesis one? And if it is done already what is it called?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no reason why basic and acidic groups could not coexist being attached to different carbons of the carbon chain, when they can coexist on the same carbon of aminoacids $\ce{H2N-CHR-COOH}$, occuring free or condensed in proteins in living cells.

These aminoacids exchange protons via $\ce{H+(aq)}$, forming [zwitterions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwitterion) $\ce{H3N^{+}-CHR-COO-}$, neutralizing themselves.

For longer chains, consider e.g. $\ce{H2N-(CH2)_n-COOH}$ with an acidic and a basic group at the ends (simple example is GABA, $\gamma$-aminobutyric acid, a natural neurotransmitter where $n=3$). similarly as above, in water solution they would exist as zwittterions. In strongly acidic/basic solutions, only amino/carboxy group would have charge, respectively.

For $n=5$, it is epsilon-aminokaproic acid with an acidic and a basic group. Its cyclical lactam with amidic bond $\ce{-CO-NH-}$ is used as the monomer for the original polyamide Silon $\ce{[-NH-(CH2)_5-CO-]_n}$, with more simple production, compared to the Nylon-66. It was produced in the post-WW-II Czechoslovakia. For the curiosity, it was invented by famous Czech organic chemist Otto Wichterle, who invented also soft contact lenses.

Analogically, the above occurs for other acidic and basic groups, e.g.: $\ce{R1-NH-R2-SO3H ->[H2O]R1-NH2^{+}-R2-SO3-}$.

Comment: Can you cite a reference for Wichterle as well as inventor? If Wikipedia is to be believed both IG Farben and Toray first developed nylon 6 in 1938. Wichterle is not mentioned

Comment: @Andrew https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Wichterle // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nylon_6 // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silon // (CZ2EN)  https://cs-m-wikipedia-org.translate.goog/wiki/Silon?_x_tr_sl=cs&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=cs&_x_tr_pto=wapp

Comment: those pages give a date of 1940 for Wichterle’s nylon work. Farben’s patent was filed in 1938: https://patents.google.com/patent/US2241321A/en

Comment: It could be parallel work. He worked on it secretly to hide it from nacists. Perhaps he improved the synthesis. I assume he was not in position and circumstances to get it patented.